# Creating JSON output in Java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to create below JSON in Java.

```
"data": {
    "keys": ["access_token"]
}
```

I have tried below code for same

```
JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
JSONArray keys = new JSONArray();
keys.add("access_token");
jsonObjSend.put("keys", keys);
data.put("data",keys);
System.out.println(obj.toString());
```

Comment: And what have you tried to do?

Comment: post your code as a part of your question with appropriate formatting.

Comment: Then whats the problem

Comment: What's the problem. What kind of output does your code produce?

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrongly. you need to add `data` to `jsonObjSend` check this.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray keys = new JSONArray();
    keys.put("access_token");
    data.put("keys", keys);
    jsonObjSend.put("data",data);
    System.out.println(jsonObjSend.toString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please mind the desired output is not a valid JSON:

```json
"data": {
  "keys": [
    "access_token"
  ]
}
```

A valid JSON would be:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "keys": [
      "access_token"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

Once you are using the [`org.json`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library to work with JSON, you might find the following code useful:

```java
JSONObject root = new JSONObject();

JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
root.put("data", data);

JSONArray keys = new JSONArray();
keys.put("access_token");
data.put("keys", keys);

String json = root.toString();
```

It will produce this JSON:

```json
{"data": {"keys": ["access_token"]}}
```

Comment: is there any way to pass BIG json data ??

Comment: @AltamashShaikh I haven't tried with big JSON data and have no idea what *big JSON data* means for you. You could try.

Comment: BIG json data means i was trying to make a http call with json as payload , so i tried with JSON parser and it worked for me :)

Comment: @AltamashShaikh If it worked for you, please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using google gson Json.

Have a look to the sample code

```
JsonObj obj = new JsonObj(); 
Data data = new Data();
String keys[] = {"access_token"};
data.setKeys(keys);

obj.setData(data);
System.out.println("==================>>>"+gson.toJson(obj));


class JsonObj{
    private Data data;
    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
class Data{
    private String[] keys;

    public String[] getKeys() {
        return keys;
    }
    public void setKeys(String[] keys) {
        this.keys = keys;
    }
}
```